# How to disallow increment operator when operated multiple times on a object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, increment, lvalue-to-rvalue

How do I overload the increment operator so that this code becomes invalid -

```
Point p(2, 3);
++++p;
```

while allowing the following -

```
Point p(2, 3), a(0, 0), b(1, 4);
a = ++p + b;
```

Like in C this would be invalid -

```
int a = 2;
++++a;
```

Comment: *How do I overload the increment operator so that this code becomes invalid* -- I will be honest with you -- is it this important to make sure a crazy C++ programmer won't write crazy code?  Whatever you come up with, a C++ programmer will bypass it with code that will be even crazier.

Comment: I've never seen "++++"-anything before.  Why is it important to prohibit this behavior?

Comment: @DimitrijeKostic I just want it to resemble C. If there's no way to achieve it then I guess that's ok. But it's just a curiosity of mine

Comment: @IrtiazKabir If `operator++` is overloaded for your `Point` class (i.e., if `++p` is meaningful) then it seems neither possible nor reasonable to stop someone from applying that operator twice.

Comment: @DimitrijeKostic ++ an int is meaningful as well. But why isn't ++++ int meaningful then? If `int` is expressing this behavior then why not `Point` ?

Comment: @IrtiazKabir `++++i` where `i` is an `int` will compile just fine in C++. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/pMuxT3KQf). Additionally, why do you want it to resemble `C` ?  In particular, in `C++` `++++i` is compilable.

Comment: @AnoopRana in C it doesn't

Comment: @AnoopRana `++++i;` is OK in C++ but ***not in C***.

Comment: @IrtiazKabir Why do you want it to resemble C instead of C++? In C++, `++++a` is valid. If one is writing C++, one should try writing C++ not C.

Comment: *Why* the OP wants to do this is not really an issue, IMHO. The fact that they ***do*** want to do it but don't know how, makes this a perfectly valid question for Stack Overflow. My answer may not be the best approach, but it is one possible avenue for the OP to explore.

Comment: @IrtiazKabir -- Maybe the entire issue is that C++ allows operator overloading -- that concept does not exist in `C`.  The `++` behavior is baked into C, and there is no flexibility, while in C++, an overloaded `operator ++` is an actual function, complete with return types, and if some programmer feels like it, have side effects.  You are trying to control what comes naturally to C++ and operator overloading.

Comment: @AnoopRana Being related is not the qualification for a dupe target. Duping is also not the correct vector for giving advice.

Comment: `++++a` is only allowed in C++ with overloaded `operator++()` functions (so disallowed for basic types like `int`). I recall a paper (will try to find a reference) that said chaining of overloaded `operator++()` is allowed in C++ because (1) a lot of other consequential changes needed to prevent it and keep the language consistent (2) such hacks rarely used outside obfuscated coding contests, and (3) it sucks for readability but actually isn't particularly harmful. (i.e. a lot of work to prevent for not much real-world benefit) I suspect the same would apply in writing C++ code to prevent it.

Comment: In C++, defensive programming protects you from Murphy, but not from Machiavelli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you *could* do this is to make your `operator++()` return a `const` reference. That would prevent subsequent modification of the returned value, as in a 'chained' `++++p;`.

Here's an outline version that also includes the required binary addition operator, implemented as a non-member function ([as is normal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/10871073)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Point {
public:
    int x{ 0 }, y{ 0 };
    Point(int a, int b) : x{ a }, y{ b } {}
    const Point& operator++() { ++x; ++y; return *this; }
    Point& operator+=(const Point& rhs) { x += rhs.x; y += rhs.y; return *this; }
};

inline Point operator+(Point lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

int main()
{
    Point p(2, 3), a(0, 0), b(1, 4);
    a = ++p + b; // OK: The result of the ++p is passed by value (i.e. a copy)
    std::cout << a.x << " " << a.y << "\n";
//  ++++a; // error C2678: binary '++': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Point'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing is that a reference to a local variable is being returned and that's not a big deal.. The program crashes for some reason

Comment: @IrtiazKabir Oops - fixed (for now) by returning by value. Will investigate better options ...

Comment: @IrtiazKabir Does it still crash with the dangling reference issue fixed? I get an output of `4 8`, as expected ... and no warnings from clang-cl or MSVC, or their code analyzers.

Comment: No now it's fine

Comment: Returning a `const` reference from `operator++()` would not necessarily prevent something like `a = ++p + b;` from working.   For `a = ++p + b` to be broken, there would also need to be an `operator+()` that accepts a non-const first argument (e.g. a non-member overload of`operator+(P &p, const B &b)`).      The bigger problem would be that returning a `const` reference from `operator++()` potentially breaks more than chaining of `++`  (e.g. it can break things other than `++++++p` in ways that will be a bit counter-intuitive) but would not break things consistently.

Comment: @Peter Yeah. I've changed my answer to use more idiomatic operators, which are fine with the `const& ++` operator. But the fact that the proposed solution may also break other things *may* even be what OP is looking for. The pre-increment in **C** returns an rvalue but trying to implement an rvalue-returning overload sounds a bit like a nightmare ... `const&` strikes me as a "reasonable compromise".